# Sigma field generated by an arbitrary random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-expectation, sigma-algebra

Q) Take $\Omega=[0,1]$, with the $\sigma$-field of Borel sets and $P$ the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1].$Find $E(\xi |\eta)$ for $\xi(x)=2x^2$,
$\eta(x) = \begin{cases} 2, & \mbox{if } x\in[0,\frac{1}{2}), \\ x, & \mbox{if } x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]. \end{cases}$

The definition I'm using is,Let $\xi$ be an integrable random variable and let $\eta$ be an arbitrary random
variable. Then the conditional expectation of $\xi$ given $\eta$ is defined to be a random
variable $E(\xi|\eta)$ such that

1. $E(\xi |\eta)$ is a $\sigma(\eta)$-measurable;
2. For any $A\in\sigma(\eta), \displaystyle\int_{A}E(\xi|\eta)dP=\displaystyle\int_{A}\xi dP.$

This is how I tried:in order to find elements of $\sigma(\eta)$,if the Borel set,$B$ only contains $2$, then it's inverse will be the event $\{\eta=2\}=[0,\frac{1}{2})$.If $B\subset[\frac{1}{2},1]$, then it's inverse $\eta^{-1}(B)$. If $B$ contains $2$ or $[\frac{1}{2},1]$, then it's inverse will be union of the previous 2 cases. If $B$ doesn't contain $2$ and $[\frac{1}{2},1]$ then it's inverse will be $\phi$. Since $\sigma(\eta)$ is a $\sigma$-field with elements of the form $\eta^{-1}(B)$, where $B\in B(R)$,I thought this 4 elements will be the elements of $\sigma(\eta)$,and it satisfies definition of $\sigma$
-field also. Is this the correct approach?

I was able to find the value of $E(\xi|\eta)(x)$ when $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})$ to be $\frac{1}{6}$.
For $E(\xi|\eta)$ to be $\sigma(\eta)$-measurable, it must be constant on $[0,\frac{1}{2})$,as $\eta$ is constant there. So the value 1/6.

Also,$\displaystyle\int_{A}E(\xi|\eta)(x)dx=\int_{A}\eta(x)dx=\frac{1}{12}$, where $A=\{\eta=\frac{1}{2}\}$,where $x\in[0,\frac{1}{2})$.

How do I calculate $E(\xi|\eta)$ when $x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$? How do I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: You have really overcomplicated things...   Let's assume $\eta(x) = 0.75$.  Then $x = 0.75$,  Therefore, $\xi(x) = 2\cdot 0.75^2 = 1.125$.  Therefore, $\mathbb{E}\xi|\eta = 1.125$, since that is the actual value of $\xi$.   Given this example, you should be able to work out the answer to the question.

Comment: Oh ok,so when $x\in [\frac{1}{2},1]$,then $E(\xi|\eta)=2x^2$,right?So I didn’t have to find all the elements of $\sigma(\eta)$?

Comment: No, but as a further note the expectation is conditional upon $\eta$, so you should write the right hand side in terms of $\eta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively (e.g., from the partial information or experimenter point of view as described in Section 4 of Billinglsley's *Probability and Measure*), if one observes $\eta = 2$, $x$ must be in $[0, 1/2)$, which is the domain of $\xi$, hence $E[\xi|\eta]_x = \int_0^{1/2} 2x^2 \frac{1}{1/2}dx = \frac{1}{6}$. The factor "$\frac{1}{1/2}$" reflects the fact that the "conditional" probability space shrinks to $[0, 1/2)$, instead of $[0, 1]$ anymore after $\eta = 2$ is observed. Alternatively, if one observes $\eta = x \in [1/2, 1]$, then he actually observed the exact sample point $x$ in $\Omega$ and consequently he would be certain that $\xi = 2x^2$, whence $E[\xi|\eta]_x = 2x^2$.

Consolidating the above two cases to one expression, one have
\begin{align}
E[\xi|\eta] = \frac{1}{6}I_{\{2\}}(\eta) + 2\eta^2I_{[1/2, 1]}(\eta). \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
Or if you want to make the variable $x$ explicit, this is
\begin{align}
E[\xi|\eta]_x &= \frac{1}{6}I_{\{2\}}(\eta(x)) + 2\eta(x)^2I_{[1/2, 1]}(\eta(x)) \\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{6} & x \in [0, 1/2] \\[1em]
2x^2 = \xi(x) & x \in [1/2, 1]
\end{cases} \\
&= \frac{1}{6}I_{[0, 1/2)}(x) + \xi(x)I_{[1/2, 1]}(x). \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

Note that expression $\eqref{1}$ is more handy to verify the first requirement in the conditional expectation definition while expression $\eqref{2}$ is more handy to verify the second requirement in the conditional expectation definition, as shown below.

As $\eqref{1}$ is clearly a function of $\eta$, $E[\xi|\eta]$ is certainly $\sigma(\eta)$-measurable.  To formally verify the second requirement in the conditional expectation definition, it suffices to show  (why?)
\begin{align}
\int_A \xi(x) dx = \int_A E[\xi|\eta]_x dx 
= \frac{1}{6}\lambda({A \cap [0, 1/2)}) + \int_{A \cap [1/2, 1]}\xi(x)dx \tag{3}\label{3} 
\end{align}
holds for every $A = \{x \in [0, 1]: \eta(x) \leq y\}$, where $y \in \mathbb{R}$. There are the following three cases:

1. $y < 1/2$, then $A = \varnothing$, for which $\eqref{3}$ holds trivially.
2. $1/2 \leq y < 2$, then $A = [1/2, \min(y, 1)]$, which does not intersect the interval $[0, 1/2)$ and is fully contained in the interval $[1/2, 1]$, hence $\eqref{3}$ holds.
3. $ y \geq 2$, then $A = [0, 1] = \Omega$, for which $\int_0^1 \xi(x)dx = \int_0^1 2x^2 dx = \frac{2}{3}$, and $\frac{1}{6}\lambda([0, 1/2)] + \int_{1/2}^1 2x^2 dx = \frac{1}{12} + \frac{2}{3}\left(1 - \frac{1}{8}\right) = \frac{2}{3}$, hence $\eqref{3}$ holds.

This completes the proof.  For a similar but slightly more complicated problem, check [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545113/find-conditional-expectation-mathbbeyx/1545170#1545170).

Comment: Does $I_{\{2\}}\eta$ in expression $(1)$ mean Indicator function?

Comment: Also,what is $\lambda$ in expression $(3)$?

Comment: @AY Yes, $I$ means the indicator function. And $\lambda$ is a common notation for Lebesgue measure.